# Session ASP.NET doesnt seem to work

Tags: asp.net, session

I have the following code on my default.aspx

`Label1.Text = Session("valueName").ToString()`

And the following code on my login.aspx

Dim strCon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Goed").ConnectionString

```
    'Create Connection String And SQL Statement
    Dim strSelect As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_LogIn WHERE Gebruiker = @Gebruiker AND Wachtwoord = @Wachtwoord"

    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strCon)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = strSelect

    Dim Gebruiker As New SqlParameter("@Gebruiker", _
                                      SqlDbType.VarChar)
    Gebruiker.Value = TxtUs.Text.Trim().ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Gebruiker)

    Dim Wachtwoord As New SqlParameter("@Wachtwoord", _
                                       SqlDbType.VarChar)
    Wachtwoord.Value = TxtPw.Text.Trim().ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Wachtwoord)


    con.Open()

    Dim result As Integer = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Int32)
    con.Close()

    If result >= 1 Then
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx")

        Session("valueName") = TxtUs.Text.ToString()


    Else
        lblMsg.Text = "Gebruikers naam en of wachtwoord kloppen niet"
    End If

End Sub
```

But it doesnt seem to help. I don't get any error or whatso ever, any idea?

Comment: If you set a break point, do you hit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Redirect` method ends the execution, so you have to set the session variable before redirecting:

```
Session("valueName") = TxtUs.Text.ToString()
Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
```

Comment: Well. This is awkward... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are redirecting before setting the session.  you should first set the session and then redirect the page.

Or

Your result variable is not 1 or bigger than 1. you should check that too